# running node.js and selenium on winddows

Tags: node.js, windows, selenium, webdriver-io

I've just picked up node.js and selenium the other day so I apologize for this introductory question but I haven't been able to find an answer on this. I've written a .js script that uses webdriverio. To use this I open 2 cmd windows (I'm running off windows 7) one where I type `selenium-standalone start` to get selenium to open. Then I run in the other one `node ..../script.js` . This gets me a beautiful browser that does what it's suppose to 1/10. The other 9/10 times I get a Session deleted due to client timeout. Since this is to be quick and easy I don't really care if it times out I just want it to restart this process. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: restart which process?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, your node.js program may be trying to connect to the Selenium server, but without allowing for enough time for it to be able to establish the browser reliably too.  Perhaps a case for using `.pause(10000)` as in:

```
var Selenium = function () {
   this.client = webdriverio.remote(options);
};

Selenium.prototype.refreshURL = function (url, cb) {
   var self = this;
   this.client
     .init()
     .url(url)
     .pause(10000)
   // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround for setting a pause is to use waitFor* - there are multiple options like
http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForVisible.html
or
http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForExist.html

```
 .waitForVisible('body', 20000000).then(function(isVisible){
 //.. you can add also small timeout here to dodge low hardware lags
 });
```